# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException for IE11

Tags: java, selenium

New to selenium here, please be nice.

I'm using selenium webdriver 2.41.0 on win 7 with Internet Explorer 11 and getting the following "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == home_title (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

I'm reading the url and iedriverpath from a properties file and that bit of code is working fine as browser gets launched with the valid url.

rest of my code is

```
// Launches a browser based on the value specified in the properties file
public class LaunchBrowser {

public static WebDriver driver;
private String browser;
private String url;
private String iedriverpath;

// starts up a browser session and navigates to the url specified
@Test
public void startBrowser() throws Exception {

    switch (browser) {

        case "IE":  // Set IE driver path
            File ieFile = new File (iedriverpath);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ieFile.getAbsolutePath());
            DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            dc.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(dc);
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Browser Specified!!!");
    }

    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();        
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("home_title"));
    }
}
```

HTML for the element I'm trying to find looks like this

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="33%" style="vertical-align:top;"></td>
<td width="33%" align="center">
<input id="home_title" class="home_title" type="text" readonly="true" title="Cloud Services"    value="Cloud Services" style="width: 142px;">
</td>
<td class="text-align-right" width="33%" nowrap="true" style="vertical-align:top;">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas what could be causing the exception? Is it a sync issue or something wrong with the locator used?

Thanks heaps.

Comment: What does the structure look like above the table? Do any other drivers work?

Comment: i tried with firefox 30.0 and got the same issue

Comment: is there a way to attach a file? I can attach/upload the full html file if its of any help...

Comment: This element inside an iframe? Whats the source of the page look like higher up?

Comment: Is it a live site? I could look at. Otherwise i think you need to edit post.

Comment: spot on, it is inside an iframe

    
<iframe id="gsft_main" class="ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-  center" frameborder="0" name="gsft_main" longdesc="Content frame for content and lists loaded from the navigator" src="home_splash.do?sysparm_direct=true" title="Navigation Content" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 0px; right: 7px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 331px; width: 945px; z-index: 0; display: block; visibility: visible;">
<html class=" ltr" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<body onfocus="popupClose();"
</html>
</iframe>

Comment: Great! Answered below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch frame.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("ID of frame");
```

Then do your work.. Then switch back.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to help! Good luck with your code!